# Assigning groups

Tags: algorithm, set, combinations

I have a problem where I am to assign variables to sets. Each set has a limit of variables that can be assigned to it and each variable can be assigned to some subset of the total sets.

Example:

- `a` can be in sets `A` or `B`
- `b` can be in sets `B`
- `c` can be in sets `A` or `B`
- `d` can be in sets `A`

Thus, we can have `A: a, d; B: b, c` or `A: c, d; B: a,b` (order of variables within set does not matter)/

Of course, there will be times when it is impossible to assign all variables, times when we have multiple options, and times with only 1 option.

I feel like there is a simple version of this problem but I can't seem to place my finger on it. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd try simple backtracking, assigning most-constrained variables first (e.g. b and d in your example).

Comment: @tobias_k right but in the situation of multiple equally constrained variables, you make a copy of the list so far and rerun in order to generate all possible set combinations? This is what I thought of but seems needlessly complex - it seems like there would be a faster/simpler way to do this

Comment: Seems like the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solvable efficiently using max flow. Prepare a flow network with a unit capacity arc from a source to each variable, a unit capacity arc from each variable to each set to which it can belong, and an arc from each set to a sink of capacity equal to the capacity of the set. For example,

```
ARCS

tail head capacity
------------------
s    a    1
s    b    1
s    c    1
s    d    1
a    A    1
a    B    1
b    B    1
c    A    1
c    B    1
d    A    1
A    t    2
B    t    2
```

Use your favorite max flow algorithm that produces an integral flow and extract the assignment according to which variable to set arcs have flow.

Comment: How did you come up with this solution? I'm learning algorithms and this seems somewhat arbitrary as a way to define the problem, although I see it works after some analysis.

Comment: @nii75435eoopy For this problem specifically, the relationship between flows and assignments is a bit of a cliché. More generally if I'm trying to figure out whether a problem has a polynomial-time algorithm, I'm looking for either a dynamic program or an integer program that happens to be solvable efficiently. Dynamic programming tends not to work for assignment problems because there are too many states. Integer programming works better here; we have a 0-1 variable for each potential assignment, constraints ensuring that each problem variable is assignment and each set is not over capacity.

Comment: @nii75435eoopy Once we write down those equations and flip the signs on one group of inequalities so that everything is less than or equal to, we can observe that the matrix is [a network matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Total_unimodularity), which means that there's an polynomial-time algorithm via the network simplex method. At that point it's a question of picking out the appropriately general network flow subproblem.

Comment: @nii75435eoopy Once I have an efficient algorithm I reach into my bag of data structural tricks to see if I can make it go faster, but since this is pretty straightforwardly a flow/matching problem, there's not much point.

Comment: @nii75435eoopy There are other ways to get algorithms besides dynamic programming and linear programming (particularly for problems that involve counting an exponential number of things), but those cover the vast majority of problems in practice. Algorithms courses tend to over-emphasize divide and conquer as a technique; in my experience, it's mostly useful for understanding common sorting and search problems (and things like convex hull which deeply resembles sorting).

Comment: Ah that makes sense! From my understanding, the best way to develop the "bag of tricks" is practice. Would you say something like leetcode would be the best way forward? If not, what is?

Comment: @nii75435eoopy Yes, I practice a lot (but then I enjoy it and still do it even though I'm not planning on interviewing anytime soon). There are a lot of different competitive programming sites. I'm not familiar with leetcode but I hear that it's good for interview prep.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - max flow seems to give only one solution. Is there any way to have it output all solutions?

Comment: @user760900 I'd follow tobias_k's suggestion of backtracking then. You can use max flow to check whether it's possible to prune a particular subtree. (If this sounds too complicated, you could also pick up an SMT solver like [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3), write the constraints straightforwardly, and let it do the heavy lifting.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost as to how I would write the problem in Z3. Would you be able to write an example for the above problem for Z3?

Comment: @user760900 Basically you want to declare a `Bool` variable for each possible assignment of a variable to a set. Then you want to assert constraints that A) for each variable, the sum of its assignment `Bool`s is 1; B) for each set, the sum of its assignment `Bool`s is at most its capacity.

Comment: @user760900 don't have z3 python bindings installed, but something like `a_in_A = Bool('a_in_A'); a_in_B = Bool('a_in_B'); b_in_B = Bool('b_in_B'); c_in_A = Bool('c_in_A'); c_in_B = Bool('c_in_B'); d_in_A = Bool('d_in_A'); solve(a_in_B + b_in_B + c_in_B <= 2, a_in_A + c_in_A + d_in_A <= 2, a_in_A + a_in_B == 1, b_in_B == 1, c_in_A + c_in_B == 1, d_in_A == 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP-complete meaning there is no polynomial time solution for this.
You would have to use backtracking in this case.

Have a look at these links:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vertex-cover-problem-set-1-introduction-approximate-algorithm-2/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-cover-problem-set-1-greedy-approximate-algorithm/

Comment: How would it be modeled as a vertex/set cover?